# How to throw exception in Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api

How can I throw a exception to in ASP.net Web Api?

Below is my code:

```
public Test GetTestId(string id)
{
    Test test = _test.GetTest(id);

    if (test == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return test;
}
```

I don't think I am doing the right thing, How do my client know it is a `HTTP 404` error?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's absolutely fine.

Alternatively, if you wish to provide more info (to allow, as you say, the client to distinguish from regular 404):

```
    if (test == null)
    {
         throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
"this item does not exist"));
    }
```

Comment: But when I host it to the web server, I always get a HTTP 500 error.

Comment: @Alvin Are you inheriting your controller from ApiController? Also check if this GetTestId method is NOT called from a constructor, just to be sure. If everything fails, try the following to throw the error: throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound,"this item does not exist");

Answer (score 6):

[This blogpost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/youssefm/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi) should help you understand WebAPI error handling a bit better.

What you have in your code snippet should work. The server will send back a 404 Not Found to the client if test is null with no response body. If you want a response body, you should consider `using Request.CreateErrorResponse` as explained in the blog post above and passing that response to the `HttpResponseException`.